# how can I save user input in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, json, input, local-storage

I'm trying to save a user input from 3 different types to local storage and display them in a td. how can i do this? 
This is what I tried to do:

```
function save() {

    document.getElementsByClassName("field").each(function(formField){
        formdata[this.id] = this.value;
        document.getElementById("input"+this.id).value=this.value;
    });
    localStorage.setItem("formdata", JSON.stringify(formdata));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('formdata'));
    document.getElementById("getinput").style.display = "none";

}
```

but it didn't work and I can use some help.

this is the input and the display td:

```html
<table style="width: 50%" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Check</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="inputDate">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="inputTime">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="inputTitle">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="getinput">
    <table style="width:100%;" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none">Date:</td>
            <td style="border:none"><input class="field" id="Date" name="Text1" type="date"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none">Time:</td>
            <td style="border:none"><input class="field" id="Time" name="Text1" type="time"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none">Title:</td>
            <td style="border:none"><input class="field" id="Title" name="Text1" type="text" placeholder="Meeting details"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:center">
            <td style="border:none" colspan="2"><input name="btc" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel()">
            &nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="bts" type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: You may be trying to do too much at once. Your localstorage.setitem code looks good. Try starting with `localStorage.setItem('title', document.getElementById('Title').value` and make sure your issue isn't with your formdata variable.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which has no `each` method. So `formdata` is most likely undefined.

Comment: What type is `formdata`? Don't use the `FormData` type for this.

Comment: Aren't you getting errors in the console for that `.each()` call?

Comment: yes i'm getting errors  in the console for that .each() call but i don't know how else to do the function

Comment: @shira1954 By using loops

Answer (score 1):

Well... first, we need to check if the Browser does or not support Browser Support.

This is done by checking:

```
function doesSupportStorage(){
  return (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined");
}
```

If the browser does support storage then we can set and get items:

```
if (doesSupportStorage()){

  // Store item
  localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

  // Load item and show in console
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("key")

  // Remove item
  localStorage.removeItem("key");
}
```

Note: You can access Browser Storage using `localStorage` or `window.localStorage`.

If you can't use localStorage, there are other ways that you can store such as:

- PersistJS: https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js
- globalstorage: Be aware that this is deprecated and used in old browsers.
- data attribute: You could store the information inside a JSON string as part of the data attribute
- Cookies

Answer (score 0):

`each` is a valid function and [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which doesn't support forEach.

We can also use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the HTMLCollection to an array and use forEach on the list.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("filed")).forEach(...
```

or use for, while loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {...}
```

```js
function save() {

var els = document.getElementsByClassName("field");
const formdata = {};

[].forEach.call(els, function (el) {
    
    formdata[el.id] = el.value;
    document.getElementById("input" + el.id).value= el.value;
});

if(typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
  alert('No localStorage support');
  return;
}

localStorage.setItem("formdata", JSON.stringify(formdata));
console.log(localStorage.getItem('formdata'));
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 50%" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Check</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="inputDate">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="inputTime">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="inputTitle">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="getinput">
    <table style="width:100%;" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none">Date:</td>
            <td style="border:none"><input class="field" id="Date" name="Text1" type="date"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none">Time:</td>
            <td style="border:none"><input class="field" id="Time" name="Text1" type="time"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none">Title:</td>
            <td style="border:none"><input class="field" id="Title" name="Text1" type="text" placeholder="Meeting details"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:center">
            <td style="border:none" colspan="2"><input name="btc" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel()">
            &nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="bts" type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```